# How can I use map and orElseThrow on the same line?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to construct an object from an Optional object, and throw an exception if the Optional object is not present.

```
@GetMapping("/{productId}")
    public ProductResponse getOneProduct(@PathVariable Long productId) {
        Optional<Product> foundProductOpt = productRepository.findById(productId);
        return foundProductOpt.map(() ->
               new ProductResponse(product, "ok").orElseThrow(() ->
                       new EntityNotFoundException("Product with id " +
                                                   productId + "was not found"));
    }
```

Been googling and it seems that I cannot use the map method this way where I would like to find a Product using findById and then put it into a foundProductOpt variable and then instantiate a response object with the found Product as well as a message along with it.

How can I pass an object from an Optional into a method or constructor, or throw an exception if the object is not present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
return foundProductOpt
    .map(() -> new ProductResponse(product, "ok")
    .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(
        "Product with id " + productId + "was not found"));
```

To:

```
return foundProductOpt
    .map(p -> new ProductResponse(p, "ok"))
    .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException(
        "Product with id " + productId + "was not found"));
```

Formatting such long lines correctly improves readability. Besides, you were not using [`Optional.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map(java.util.function.Function)) and [`Optional.orElseThrow`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)) correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to map anything. Just throw if not present. Here's how I'd think it through:

First pretend the Optional is a real object and everything is ok.

```
return new ProductResponse(foundProductOpt
                           , "ok");
```

Then convert the Optional using `orElseThrow()`.

```
return new ProductResponse(foundProductOpt // Unchanged
        .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Not found"))
                           , "ok"); // Unchanged
```